# Rails: Nested where clauses in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

TLDR: I can't get the where clause to work in a nested (either 1 or 2 levels of nesting down) has_many association

```
#Author.rb
has_many :posts


#Post.rb
belongs_to :author
has_one :post_setting


#PostSetting.rb
#Has attributes like draft (bool), flagged(bool), etc.

belongs_to :post
```

Now, if I am trying to create an association in Author which finds all the posts where post_setting.draft = false, for example, like below.

```
has_many :published_posts,
  -> {
       includes(:post_setting)
       .where(post_setting: {draft: false})
       .distinct
     },
  class_name "Post"
```

That, unfortunately, fails with the following error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "post_setting"
```

Alternatively, I'd like to be able to do the following as well -

```
#Group.rb
has_many :authors
has_many :posts,
  -> {
       includes(:post_setting)
       .where(post_setting: {draft: false})
       .distinct
     },
through: authors
```

In general, I feel I am not very clear on the rules around how where/joins/includes work in associations. Would it be more advisable to create a scope on posts than include that in the `has_many` in author?

Thank you!

PS. I am using Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your queries work you should use proper naming:

```
has_many :published_posts,
  -> {
       includes(:post_setting)
       .where(post_settings: {draft: false}) # Note the plural table name
       .distinct
     },
  class_name "Post"
```

This can be confusing but generally conditions use the underlying table name, while `joins` and `includes` use the association name.

If you have reasons to limit the dataset available through an association to match some criteria, use the association condition defined on the parent model.

If there is no such reason and you want to keep flexibility on filtering the associated dataset, use scopes defined on the referenced model.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and pointing out the naming. On doing that, I still receive the following error: 
`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column post_settings.draft does not exist` Thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Could you post your `post_settings` table schema from `db/schema.rb` here?

Comment: Actually, your solution worked - thanks so much! For the second part of the question, you mentioned using 'scopes defined on the reference model'. How can I then use scopes in a `has_many` relationship? Lets say I defined a scope on `Post` for published posts. How can I now use it in `Group.rb` or `Author.rb`? Use a merge? (Is that performance efficient?)

Comment: When you chain scopes there is no merge if that's what you're talking about. The query is built lazily and gets actually executed when a terminating method such as `first` or `to_a` gets applied. You can have as many scopes on any model as you want and chain them as you see fit, e.g. `Posts.published.recent.by_date` or what have you, each being a separately defined scope. You can also combine that with conditions, e.g.  `@author.posts.published` (this will apply a `WHERE` clause). Eventual SQL will reflect all the scopes and criterias combined.

Comment: Sorry, I asked two different questions which muddled the waters. To clarify: You mentioned `@author.posts.published`. Can I write that as a `has_many` relationship while still using the published scope on `posts`? That might make it easier for me to use in other associations with `authors` (like `Group` in the above example)?

Comment: I don't seem to understand, sorry. The `@author.posts.published` already provides filtering semantic for posts. There is no need to make it more explicit via `has_many` condition. If `published` is a scope defined on `Post` then yes, you will be able to also use it independently of authors, e.g. `Group.last.posts.published`.